# Find depth of partially filled hemisphere.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A hemisphere of radius length $5 cm$ is partially filled with water. The top of the hemisphere is horizontal and the surface of the water is a circle of radius $4 cm$.  Find the depth of the water. I tried to draw a diagram, but wasn't sure. How can I diagramatically represent this problem?

Comment: Could you please show us a picture of the diagram which you aren't sure about? We can help you better if you do so.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to diagramatically represent this problem, but the diagram below is helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the diagram below.  Since the top of the hemisphere and the water are both horizontal, we can draw a right triangle whose hypotenuse is a radius of the hemisphere, horizontal leg is a radius of the water, and whose vertical leg extends from the center of the top of the hemisphere to the center of the water's surface.  The radius of the water is $4~\text{cm}$.  Since the hemisphere has radius $5~\text{cm}$ and the water has depth $h$, the vertical leg of the right triangle is $5~\text{cm} - h$.  Can you finish?

[image: hemisphere_partially_filled_with_water]